# Simple home page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

First thing to learn about codeigniter should be how to create a simple view which is the appearance of your web application?. I had tried so many tutorials on Internet for making a MVC and always succeeded but when i try to make my own home page of site my myself i always failed.

The only thing that showed up is:

> **"404 Page Not Found 
>  The page you requested was not found. "**

I just want a simple thing. When anyone open *www.mywebsite.com* my home page must be open.

**Is this necessary to make a model if there is no database work in needed?**

Now i tell you what i did myself to make my home page. 
1. First of all i made a file `'index.php'` in view folder (Simple HTML file).
2. I added a file `'index_controller.php'` in controller folder. (see code below)

```
class Index_controller extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('index');
}
}
```

What more should i do to make my code working?

Comment: what is the URL you are accessing, I mean do you include index.php in your URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this necessary to make a model if there is no database work in needed?

- Nope.

You probably are missing one thing, the default controller.
If you try now,

> http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php/index_controller

it'll work right ?

But

> http://www.mywebsite.com

won't because you have to tell codeigniter that it must load by default Index_controller.

You can define that in application/config/routes.php :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Index_controller';
```

Comment: It still showing the same when accessing http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php/index_controller

Comment: Just to be sure, you didn't try `mywebsite.com` as it stands ?

Comment: No. I am learning using localhost and when i tried tutorials on Internet, They all work fine then why not a simple page(view) is working.
My Url is : http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/index_controller

Comment: When you first installed CI, there was a default controller `Welcome`. Did it worked ? Have you changed something in index.php ? Have you set `base_url` correctly in config.php (must be `http://localhost/Codeigniter/`)?

Comment: welcome worked correctly, No. Didn't changed anything in index.php, base url : $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter/';

Comment: there is http:// but dnt knw why it not show here. .htaccess = Deny from all

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$/index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72304/discussion-between-abhimanu-and-adrienxl).